# Should I avoid fuzzing the error handling code

Tags: testing, error-handling, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

Error handling code plays an important role in programming, hence, when I test the program with afl, should I pay attention to the error handling code part, or should I avoid this part from fuzzing.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling code can certainly contain bugs, so there's no reason to keep it out. You may want to configure your instrumentation to ignore common error results or error conditions.